# Android Studio Workaround: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore

Tags: android

I have to import over 1000 images into an android studio project that I cannot change the names of, and a good amount of them start with numbers and/or include capital letters.

Is there any way around this error or a way to ignore the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use these as drawable resources, you have no choice but to follow the naming rules.

You are welcome to package these images in `assets/` and use them via `AssetManager` and its `open()` method. If these are larger images (e.g., photos), `AssetManager` is the better choice anyway.